# Show a HTML code in a HTML page using PHP nl2br OR str_replace does not work

Tags: php, html

Please help tried all ways nothing worked. I am inserting some code to MySQL DB using PHP 7 and after insert the code which is all fine; thus:

```
Eg:
<p>Hello:<b>Amber</b>\r\n<div>\r\n<hr>\r\n\r\n<button onclick=\"insertTextAtCursor()\">Lisa sisend</button>
```

When I call the record set using PHP in the HTML this is NOT showing anything since the HTML codes are hidden.

My Need is to show the HTML code in Plain text BUT "without \r\n shown Line Breaks" - formatted; thus:

```
Eg:
<p>Hello:<b>Amber</b>
<div>
<hr>

<button onclick=\"insertTextAtCursor()\">Lisa sisend</button>
```

Pure css and javascrpt code's are shown nicely with this PHP lines but NOT the HTML:

```
$author_code1 = null;
$author_code1 = $row["author_code1"];  
$author_code1 = str_replace('\r\n', '<br />', $row['author_code1']);
echo $author_code1;
```

Got closer to it adding thus:

```
<?php
echo "<xmp>";
echo str_replace("\r\n", "<br/>", $author_code1);
echo "</xmp>";
?>
```

This shows all in one line:

```
</html>\r\n </textarea>\r\n</div>\r\n   </div>\r\n</section>\r\n<button>Lisa send</button>
```

My Question is why isn't it breaking to the next line? Like:

```
<div>
<p>Hello:<b>Amber</b></p>
</div>
<hr>    
<button>Lisa send</button>
```

Please help.

Comment: You might want to look at the function htmlentities (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Also you have to save your file with .php extension if you want to use php code in it.

Comment: Of course it is php I am talking of. I cant understand why nl2br is not breaking the \r\n to another line.<?php echo nl2br("$author_code1"); ?> the html is all hidden. Please tell me a way in code to make it show the html...

Comment: It appears that you have literally the characters "\r\n" in your string, not a carriage return and a newline character. Try replacing `'\r\n'` (single quotes!) with `<br>`…

Comment: <?php
echo "<xmp>";
echo str_replace("\r\n", "<br/>", $author_code1);
echo "</xmp>";
?>  

Did still no

Comment: No, `str_replace('\r\n', ...)`! Within single quotes, `\r\n` is not interpreted. Within double quotes, `\r\n` means *carriage return and newline character*.

Comment: Yes - $author_code1 = str_replace('\r\n', '', $author_code1); thank you for the answer. Keeping it empty removed the \r\n added from the Mysql. But I will be pleased to have it r\n replaced with <br/> so that the spacing is added 

This is never working with space. Adding <br> also shows all in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it provide answers to a Large extent. Many just reply and some copy paste. However, I found a solution:

```
$author_code1 = null;
$author_code1 = $row["author_code1"];  

$author_code1 = str_replace('\r\n','', $author_code1);
$author_code1 = str_replace('<',"&lt;",     $author_code1);
$author_code1 = str_replace('>',"&gt;",     $author_code1);
$author_code1 = str_replace('</',"&lt;/",   $author_code1);


<pre>
 <code class="html hljs">

<!-- my db code -->
   <?php echo $author_code1; ?>
<!-- my db code -->

 </code>
</pre>
```